# RSS feeds returning wrong tags

Tags: bug, tags, feed

I have a couple of tag RSS feeds set up across multiple sites, and apparently starting on January 2nd, occasionally the feeds are fetching data for a completely different tag.

For example, on January 2nd, the [cics](/questions/tagged/cics) tag feed (https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=cics&sort=newest) fetched a number of questions tagged with [github-api](/questions/tagged/github-api).  An hour or so ago, the [zos](/questions/tagged/zos) (https://serverfault.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=zos&sort=newest) tag fetched a number of questions tagged with [github-api](/questions/tagged/github-api) as well. This isn't repeatable, exactly, because when I've fetched the tag manually, the resulting XML doesn't have any of these questions in them, but they show up in my feed reader.

Comment: Maybe related (MSO): [Tags behaving oddly this New Year's Day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422443/tags-behaving-oddly-this-new-years-day)

Comment: Seems very reasonable, yes.

Comment: I had this happen too, a search for `mcap` returned a bunch of results that seemed to be related to `wix`.

Comment: This may be my problem too: [Is it possible for the RSS feed to erroneously publish questions that don't match the query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386084/is-it-possible-for-the-rss-feed-to-erroneously-publish-questions-that-dont-matc)

Comment: Happening to other tags as well https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387370/152193

Comment: It just happened again at 19:08 UTC with the `kedro` feed of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Reported again [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388736/165261).

Comment: Still happening for me occasionally in Slack.

Comment: Each time this happens I get about ~30 posts dumped in to the Slack RSS integration in one shot. Today 09/08  [google-apps-script] on my subscription to [q]. On 27/07 tagged [android] on my [pykx] subscription.

Comment: We are also seeing this blow up our Slack integration.

Comment: Just checking in to say this is still happening! 

Comment: Related on MSO: [RSS feeds regularly send glut of wrongly messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427065)

Comment: Me too. Lots of answers for the python tag in my query for the Rascal tag.