# Stack Overflow Atom tag feed sometimes leaks unrelated questions

Tags: support, tags, feed, atom

We have a Slack integration with `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/kedro`, but from time to time we get questions that are completely unrelated and are not tagged with the `kedro` tag. For example, a few minutes ago (2023-03-09T17:30Z) we got `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75612408/videoindexer-ui-not-showing-all-classic-accounts`, which was even closed 7 days ago.

I don't think it's related to the Slack integration and seems like a problem with the SO feed. But at the same time, I just downloaded it and there is no trace of that question.

The "meta" question would be "Has this happened to anyone else?" For tips on how to can we debug the issue further, I'll refer to Stack Overflow or Super User.

Comment: "Slack integration" - this is related to [tag:stack-overflow-for-teams], right? Please read the tag info, you need to file your issue somewhere else :)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423071/rss-feed-for-a-tag-erroneously-including-other-data

Comment: Not related to Teams, @Glorfindel. The Slack integration appears to be just configuring Slack to process an RSS feed. This is a feature of public Stack Overflow. You can tell because it's coming from `stackoverflow.com`. Teams has a separate domain name now. If you like, you can send this over to MSO, where it'll surely end up closed as a dupe of the question rene linked.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks - you mean I can set up a Slack integration with one of the Meta feeds? Because that would mean it is applicable to all sites in the network, hence on-topic here as well (though it's good to have it MSO as well, as it's most likely to be used on SO).

Comment: I believe that all SE sites do have an RSS feed for tags (this is actually what the chat feeds generally use to post questions of interest into a particular room, and since it's just a bog-standard RSS feed, I see no reason you couldn't use it with Slack, although I've never actually used Slack myself). Therefore, you raise a good point, @Glorfindel, about this being on-topic here on the global Meta.

Comment: It just happened again at 19:08 UTC with the `kedro` feed of Stack Overflow.