# RSS feed returns wrong results

Tags: bug, feed

I'm using the [Slack RSS app](https://slack.com/apps/A0F81R7U7-rss) to display results from the RSS feed from a tag. Specifically, I'm using `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=foxglove-studio&sort=newest` to display the [[foxglove-studio]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foxglove-studio) tag.

This sometimes works:

- [How to use Foxglove WebSocket server show a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76042021/how-to-use-foxglove-websocket-server-show-a-model)

[image]

But more often than not, the results are total garbage. For example, in this case, it returned **results that appear to be tagged `[synology]` rather than `[foxglove-studio]`**:

- [Docker Compose does not restart dependable containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75906046/docker-compose-does-not-restart-dependable-containers)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75909652/can-a-network-alias-persist-without-an-interface
- [apt-cacher-ng docker configuration problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75925251/apt-cacher-ng-docker-configuration-problem)
- [MSQ Backup Script DB Server is not right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75951475/msq-backup-script-db-server-is-not-right)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75976183/i-cannot-use-cmd-or-other-scripts-to-visit-the-nas-which-is-linked-to-my-windows

[image]

The results returned always seem to have one tag in common, but it's always a different tag.

Comment: No, but it asks my question :)

Comment: Do we know if this is reproducible with the chat Feeds integration?  We could set up a room to try to reproduce it.

Comment: Sure, could be worth trying!

Comment: Alright, created https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253375/rss-tags-test with the feed URL from this post.

Comment: It just happened again in my Slack channel, returning results from the `[ionic-framework]` tag. I don't see those in the chat room, so I guess at least it doesn't happen at exactly the same time.